# In Power BI, how to filter an histogram on 12 Last Months with ignoring page date filter

Tags: filter, graph, powerbi, dax, dashboard

I have a PBI Dashboard containing some KPIs and we can filter the page on date(months). I want to add an histogram which will plot data on the last 12 Months of the month chosen on the page filter. The problem is that when filtering a month on a page i will not be able to plot other months' data.